# What are the "Daśa bhāskara kṣetrās"?

Tags: puranas, temple, surya

Srisailam is one of the most ancient kshetras in our country. There are legends associated with this sacred place. Srisailam is one of only three kshetras which is a jyotirlinga Kshetra and also a Shakti peetha. The other two are Kashi and Ujjain.

SriSailam is one of the 12 Jyotirlingas. The jyotirlinga at this place is called Mallikarjuna jyotirlinga. This is also one of the 18 shakti peethas. The neck part of Sati Devi fell in this place. The deity form of goddess is Bhramaramba.

Besides this information, I have read in a magazine that this place is also one of daśa bhāskara kṣetras.

Other Bhāskara kṣetrās I found are

- [Thirukkudanthai - Sri Sarangapani Perumal Temple, Kumbakonam](http://www.sparthasarathy.com/vaishnava/ddesam/012.html). This is also one of the 108 divya desams. Divya desams are sacred places for Sri Vaishnavas.
- [Surya Narayana temple](http://www.tirumala.org/TemplesAtTiruchanoor.aspx) near [Tiruchanoor Padmavati temple](http://www.tirumala.org/PatAtThiruchanoorTempleLegend.aspx) located in the state of Andhra Pradesh.

  - I want to know what is a Bhāskara kṣetram?
  - what are the other Bhāskara kṣetrās?
  - Is there any mention of any of these  kṣetrās in any puraṇa like that of Jyotirlingās and other sacred places?

Comment: Other Bhasakara Kshetras are Konark, Prayag, and Hampi. Where did you read that there are 10 Bhaskara Kshetras

Comment: In a newspaper. It said that Sri Sailam is also a Dasha Bhaskara kshetra. Sri Kala hasti is also one.